# Eclipse plugin- Maven transitive dependency issue

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin

I am facing issue with velocity jar issue. As one of the eclipse plugin dependent on CXF bundle.
jar dependency defined in pom.xml  as below,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

another eclipse plugin dependent on custom bundle jar which has 
  jar dependency defined in pom.xml  as below,

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
       <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
       <version>1.7</version>
 </dependency>
```

On runtime I am geting issue as,
Could not find Velocity template file: org/apache/cxf/tools/wsdlto/frontend/jaxws/template/build.vm

To identify the issue I run the command,

mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose

This shows maven omitting velocity jar from cxf as it loads another velocity in classpath.

How to resolve this jar dependency ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `<exclusions>` tag for the dependency you not want:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
               <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
           <exclusion>
        <exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Project requires velocity in cxf bundle and custom bundle jar too. That's why I am not able to exclude.

Comment: @Shridevi You can not have two jars with same classes in one project